# Java Exception Error Enumerations Anti-pattern

Tags: java, exceptions, enum

Over the years I've many times seen folks enumerate error codes for exceptions in Java. I generally have felt this leads to more tedious code and does not provide value.

For example, there will be an `enum` like this `ErrorType`, often times with a numeric `errorCode`, which I find additionally egregious.

```
package so.example;

public enum ErrorType {
  INVALID_DATA_FORMAT(1000),
  MISSING_REQUIRED_FIELD(1010),
  MODIFY_DISABLED(2020),
  DUPLICATE_MERCHANT(2050),
  UNKNOWN_RESELLER(2051),
  XML_PARSING_FAILURE(2999),
  SYSTEM_ERROR(3000),
  AND_HUNDREDS_MORE_LIKE_THIS(4444);

  private final int errorCode;

  ErrorType(final int errorCode) {
    this.errorCode = errorCode;
  }

  public int getErrorCode() {
    return errorCode;
  }
}
```

Then there will be an `Exception` subclass which requires this `enum` as a construction parameter, like

```
package so.example;

public class SoExampleException extends GenericExampleException {

  public SoExampleException(ErrorType subtype, String message) {
    super(subtype, message);
  }

  public SoExampleException(ErrorType subtype, Exception causedBy) {
    super(subtype, causedBy);
  }
}
```

with code calling it like

```
  private void validate(final Request requestBody) throws SoExampleException {
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(requestBody.getSomeNumber())) {
      throw new SoExampleException(ErrorType.MISSING_REQUIRED_FIELD, "someNumber cannot be empty or null");
    }
  }
```

To me it feels like a type of anti-pattern because

1. Every time some new exception condition is dreamed up, then the enumeration has to be updated.
2. It implies callers should explicitly deal with each possible type, which makes the client exception handling tedious.
3. To me, an enumeration should really only be used for a small set of well known values, like "North, East, South, West" or "Red, Green, Blue". Having exceptions mapped to that implies that we know exactly, forever, the small set of things that can go wrong, which feels pretentious.

And the `errorCode` seems even more unnecessary considering this is an enumeration with a built-in `ordinal`.

Am I off base here? Is there a good reason for this type of pattern?

Comment: Most coding errors are not recoverable so adding numbers or codes to them is not very useful.  For strongly typed languages, extend the base error type.   In some cases, error codes can be useful, especially if your front end and back end are disparate technical stacks.  In these cases, error codes can be used for matching logic so that the client can have additional logic to deal with the error.  In most cases this is not possible and you will want a generic "Ooops, something went wrong" message.   This is the majority case so the code will be null or a general constant value.

Comment: It could be useful if you never handle the exceptions but you need errors to have codes for your external API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It implies callers should explicitly deal with each possible type, which makes the client exception handling tedious.

Yes, your calling code has to catch *each and every* Exception, then work out (from the error code) if it's an Exception that it can do something [useful] about and, if so, do whatever that is.
If it *can't* do anything, the it has to *rethrow* that same Exception and that's where this model gets *horribly* expensive.
OK, "Exception shouldn't happen often", but *every* time they do, it may take numerous "throws" before the Exception finally reaches a catch clause that can do anything [useful] with it.

For that reason alone, I'd avoid doing things this way.

I'd define Custom exception classes for each "handleable" case and throw those.  That way, a single throw will get that Exception to the correct catch clause *first time*.

IIRC, Java's "catch" clause only works at Class level, so you catch the "smallest" exception class first, and then successively "larger" ones, until you reach Exception itself.

```
catch( SubSubException ex ) { ... }
catch( SubException ex ) { ... } 
catch( Exception ex ) { ... }
```

By comparison, .Net allows you to add property "filters" into the mix as well:

```
catch( SubException ex ) when ( ex.errorCode = ErrorType.INVALID_DATA_FORMAT ) { ... } 
catch( SubException ex ) when ( ex.errorCode = ErrorType.MISSING_REQUIRED_FIELD ) { ... }
```

(Any other value of error code would bypass this catch altogether).
I've *no idea* what this does to the performance of the Exception-throwing process, though.

Comment: Now that basic pattern matching exists in Java (in switch statements) it might be possible that a similar syntax for catch blocks could be implemented in a future version, but I have to admit I'm not sure it would be a good idea. It might increase the temptation to (ab)use exception handling for flow-control...

Comment: @Hulk Good hunch -- https://mail.openjdk.org/pipermail/amber-dev/2023-December/008452.html -- This is a link where I was talking to Brian Goetz, the lead on the Pattern Matching effort in Java. He had some words to say about exactly what you are mentioning. Nothing set in stone.

Comment: @davidalayachew interesting thread - thanks for sharing!

Comment: @Hulk Anytime. Amber XXX mailing lists in the link above is where to go to find all the breaking news about Pattern Matching in Java. For example, Member Patterns just got considered this January too --- https://mail.openjdk.org/pipermail/amber-spec-experts/2024-January/003976.html

Answer (score 5):

You haven't talked about proposed alternatives to this approach so I'll answer in generalities that may not be relevant to you in a particular situation.  Usually, I would expect something like this to be done when you have a distributed system in which agreeing on the meaning of specific error codes is useful, if not extremely important.  HTTP is a decent reference: error codes have specific well-defined meanings.  If you return a 429 when you mean 403, that could be a big problem.  That's probably the argument for specifying the codes.  You don't want a code to change because someone change the order of the `enum` definition.

In such a system, the problem becomes how to manage those codes, make sure the correct codes are used and prevent redefinition of the same code with a different meaning.  That last point is something I have seen go wrong and it was ugly: the code was used to map-in a description of what happened so the description you saw in an error report wasn't always the problem that actually occurred.

There are other approaches to be sure.  I once worked on a system where the error codes were maintained in a DB table.  That included the error "can't connect to DB" (Oops!)  You could also just keep documentation which needs to be maintained like in HTTP.

But if you are going to have to maintain this documentation anyway and all (or many) of the applications in the system are built on Java, why not maintain it as an `enum` which you can then share across applications.

Now, as often happens, these kinds of things might be done for a good reason in one context and then someone repeats the approach in one where it doesn't make much sense.  For example, if you just want to display a message to the user about an error, it might be over-kill to do something like this, unless you have very specific requirements about what error messages must say in a given circumstance.

This does have a lot of the problems you mention so if you have a different approach that meets your needs, I don't see any reason you have to do this.

Comment: yes, this last example that I've distilled here has the codes stored in the database using an enum column, which means any time someone wants to update the type of errors, which are very specific and abundant, then the database definition has to be updated as well.

Comment: I would add that `AND_HUNDREDS_MORE_LIKE_THIS` is not necessary. You can have different "sequences" of codes identifying errors. Each "sequence" is strictly bound to a context. For example `ApplicationErrorCode`, `InfrastructureErrorCode`, `BusinessErrorCode`, etc. You can then have an `ErrorCode` interface all other enums implements. This way you have a generic reference for all of them.

Comment: @Kirby If these enums are simply the keys to the data in the DB, I wouldn't expect existing codes to need to be updated much.  That said, I wasn't really a fan of the DB error codes.  It allowed us to change the message without a deployment but that was a long time ago and we had long release cycles.  I'm not sure it's worth it with a faster dev-test cycle.

Answer (score 2):

So much work when it could just be:

```java
public class InvalidDataFormatException extends GenericExampleException {}
public class MissingRequiredFieldException extends GenericExampleException {}
public class ModifyDisabledException extends GenericExampleException {}
public class DuplicateMerchantException extends GenericExampleException {}
public class UnknownResellerException extends GenericExampleException {}
public class XmlParsingFailureException extends GenericExampleException {}
public class SystemErrorException extends GenericExampleException {}
public class AndHundredsMoreLikeThisException extends GenericExampleException {}
```

You can put each in a separate file. This distributes the exceptions so you're not constantly updating one centralized file that forces the team to mob the ball. All it does is add a unique descriptive name to a perfectly useful exception. Lets you give each it's own catch handler. Happens to be my favorite use of inheritance.

As for the error codes I particularly hate code bases that mix exceptions and error codes. These are different paradigms. They don't mix well. So if you use exceptions don't use error codes.

If you're stuck with error codes because of some third party but refuse to use them as error codes properly because you're in love with exceptions then you leave me no choice:

```java
public abstract class AbstractChildException extends GenericExampleException implements ErrorCode {}

public class InvalidDataFormatException extends AbstractChildException { @Override public int getErrorCode() { return 1000; } }
public class MissingRequiredFieldException extends AbstractChildException { @Override public int getErrorCode() { return 1010; } }
public class ModifyDisabledException extends AbstractChildException { @Override public int getErrorCode() { return 2020; } }
public class DuplicateMerchantException extends AbstractChildException { @Override public int getErrorCode() { return 2050; } }
public class UnknownResellerException extends AbstractChildException { @Override public int getErrorCode() { return 2051; } }
public class XmlParsingFailureException extends AbstractChildException { @Override public int getErrorCode() { return 2999; } }
public class SystemErrorException extends AbstractChildException { @Override public int getErrorCode() { return 3000; } }
public class AndHundredsMoreLikeThisException extends AbstractChildException { @Override public int getErrorCode() { return 4444; } }
```

And this is still distributable. You don't have to stick them all in one file. The only feature missing from this scheme that you had before is the ability to convert from a dynamic error code to a matching exception. Which I don't see the need for in any of your examples.

The `AbstractChildException` (yes it's a terrible name) has no body but it merges the concrete interface of `SoExampleException` with the `ErrorCode` interface letting you talk to any of these exceptions without knowing exactly which one you're talking to.  Such as:

```
catch (AbstractChildException ace) {
    System.out.println("Error code: " + ace.getErrorCode());    
}
```

> Is there a good reason for this type of pattern?

Well if you had a need to turn a dynamic error code into the matching exception sure. That feature is missing from this exception extending scheme.  Oh there is probably [some reflection magic thingy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22768526/1493294) someone could do to enable it for this exception extending scheme if it's really important. But be sure you really need it before you worry about that.

Comment: Reflecting more I why I posted this question, I realize my real reason for asking was that I couldn't think or find what it is that has inspired this same phenomenon amongst multiple code bases that I've worked with. But I think the reason is, after reading everyone's answers, is that folks are bringing the paradigm to Java  from C where error codes are used to detect exceptions.

Comment: I like error codes just fine when they aren’t mixed with exceptions. In a code base with exceptions it’s all to easy to forget that you need to save the error code returned. Saw this over and over in C++.

Answer (score 1):

> Every time some new exception conditional is dreamed up, then the enumeration has to be updated.

Well, this question is slightly orthogonal to exceptions. If you have a (large) set of error codes, do you put them into an enum or into an integer. There are arguments for both, but since your title is about exceptions ...

> It implies callers should explicitly deal with each possible type, which makes the client exception handling tedious.

Well, it implies quite the contrary to me. Having a `SoExampleException` that internally uses an enum just means that a client *may* inspect the embedded enum, or it may just decide that the details are not important.

This pattern is useful if you mostly don't care what specific error is thrown and you just want additional info that isn't a string.

Or, you have an existing system (like HTTP mentioned in the other answer, or OS error codes) that already defines (a large list of) error codes. Mapping each of those (100s) to a separate exception subclass doesn't seem all that useful to me.

> To me, an enumeration should really only be used for a small set of well known values, like "North, East, South, West" or "Red, Green, Blue".

Coming back to that: Yes. Mostly an immutable set. That's why I personally would model a system with 100s of codes not with an enum but with a simple int32 to hold the error code. That also strongly signals that the error codes are basically unbounded (which a list of 100s is anyway).

Comment: yes, I agree. I can see the value in having a numeric error code field to give an external client some non-textual value to interface with.

Answer (score 0):

Usually an enum should have few values, but in the end as many as needed. For example an enum for specifying system colours could have a large number of values, but that isn’t a problem.

One enum catching every error code is not good, because my code writing to a file for example only expects a tiny subset of all errors. Maybe sill a lot but not hundreds.

You could have an error category and a code within the category, and one error class per category. So your download code checks for download errors and doesn’t catch others.